# Python: How to resolve " 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'startswith' error" while reading large csv file in zip?

Tags: python, csv, dask

I have a 10GB csv file compressed in zip. Below is the code that I am trying to read the csv file. However, this method throwing the Attribute error. Please recommend the other fast ways to read large csv as well.

```
import zipfile as zp
import dask.dataframe as dd

file_dir = 'W:\\XYZ\\salaryofemployees.CSV.ZIP'
csv_file = "salaryofemployees.CSV"

with zp.ZipFile(file_dir) as z: 
   with z.open(csv_file) as f:
      dask_df = dd.read_csv(f)


Error: AttributeError: 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: Is this all of your relevant code?

Comment: @CaptainCaveman. Yes. That is all. Its very straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a file-like object to read_csv, but the docstring says it must be a path or list of paths

> urlpath : string or list
> Absolute or relative filepath(s). Prefix with a protocol like `s3://`
> to read from alternative filesystems. To read from multiple files you
> can pass a globstring or a list of paths, with the caveat that they
> must all have the same protocol.

Fortunately, you can use fsspec-style compound URLs for this kind of thing

```
df = dd.read_csv("zip://salaryofemployees.CSV::W:\\XYZ\\salaryofemployees.CSV.ZIP")
```

*HOWEVER*, this is a single file and compressed, so you are getting no chunking/parallelism here. Are you sure you wanted dask rather than pandas alone?

Comment: thanks for reply. Pandas datafarme taking very long time (30 mins +).

Comment: This will not be any faster, sorry.

Comment: any suggestions for alternate faster ways, to read large csv ?

Comment: Add more memory to your machine :) Could you read in x amount of rows at a time and use multi-threading?

Comment: Decompressing from ZIP is fundamentally serial. If you want parallelism, extract the file first, so it can be random accessed.